# Mongoose save() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app.js I require my model like

```
var User = require('./models/user');
app.post('/user/add', function(req,res,next){
  var newUser = new User();
  newUser.add(req.body.name, function(response){
    res.json(response);
  })
});
```

and my model (user.js) look like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports.add = function(name,callback){
    User.save({name:name}).exec(callback);
}
```

But I got error of newUser.add is not a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add instance methods to a mongoose Model you should use [instance methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) syntax:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

// Instance methods
UserSchema.methods.add = function(name, callback){
    this.name = name;
    return this.save(callback);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: why must I use userSchema.methods?

Comment: because is the mongoose way to generate the model instance, when you fetch data with mongoose it will create User objects with this methods. Its like defining the User "prototype"

Comment: @JessieEmerson It's a mongoose thing. This should help: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html Take a look at the instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

Methods can be added with methods keyword like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

userSchema.methods.add = function(name,callback){    
    User.save({name:name}).exec(callback); // not checking logic
}
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Comment: is this only for .save method? I recall I never did this.

Comment: User is not defined

Comment: I mention on comment that i don't check logic , just fixing the issue how to add methods with schema

Comment: is it only save need to use schema's method? I never use like this before. Normally I'll just do User.findOneAndUpdate()..

Comment: no , you can use save method on your controller (logics) also , like 
var newUser = new User({//data}) , then newUser.save(function(err){})

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

//schema is declared here
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var user = Mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//here we are assigning new data to user collection
//this record will not be saved here
//it will only check the schema is matching or not
//if record is matching to schema then it will assign '_id' to that record
var userRec = new user({"name":"Jessie Emerson"});

userRec.save(function(error, userDoc) {

    //this is the callback function
});
```

If you need anymore clarifications then please comment on this answer. :-)